# Do I need to dispose the FileStream object?

Tags: c#, web-services

I am pretty depressed by my programming knowledge but do we really need to dispose FileStream Object ?

Reason I am asking is because code is throwing "File being used by another process" exception once in 100 cases and for a moment as if i try again(to download file using file stream) it works fine.

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869797/file-accessed-by-another-process) for code.

Since it only happening once in 100 or so making me so confused and it's happening on production server so can't debug at all, but works perfectly on my development machine...

Comment: Unless you're returning a stream from a website method, if you can you should.

Answer (score 9):

The general rule is to dispose everything that is disposable.

In the specific case of a `FileStream`, you don't need to dispose it to close the file, you only need to use the `Close` method.

You should however dispose of the `FileStream` object anyway, as it has a finalizer. This will remove the object from the finalizer queue and make it a plain object that can be garbage collected in a single pass. If you don't dispose it, the garbage collector have to run the `Finalizer` method, and can't collect it until later, so it will linger in memory longer.

As you should dispose the object anyway, you can just put it in a `using` block. That will call the `Dispose` method, which in turn will call the `Close` method, so you don't need to do that yourself:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create(Path + file.Name)) {
  stream.Write(document, 0, document.Length);
}
```

Comment: I suppose, you don't need to call Dispose on FileStream, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524903/should-i-call-close-or-dispose-for-stream-objects FROM MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx:  Stream.Close "This method calls Dispose, specifying true to release all resources. "

Comment: @qub1n: Some classes have a `Close` method or similar that will effectively do the same as the `Dispose` method, which you can find out by reading the documentation for each class. If in doubt, it doesn't hurt to dispose disposable classes even if they have already been closed. The `using` block is a convenient way to make sure that the object is disposed properly even if there is an exception in the code.

Comment: There is a similar situation with the `Flush` and `Close` method of a file stream as with the `Close` and `Dispose` methods. You don't need to call `Flush` before closing the stream, because the `Close` method makes sure that `Flush` is called if needed.

Comment: It depend of task you are working at. It would better to called it, but i still need the answer. The question was "Do I need.." For example I am looking for bug in stacktrace from TeamCity. It seems that the problem is that one FileStream is not Closed. I see in source code that Close was called, but dispose was called. And I ask myself? It this the cause of the bug? No, because Close will release all resoruces and call Dispose.

Comment: @qub1n: If the stream isn't closed, that suggests that the `Close` call actually wasn't executed. The exception that you see might not be the exception from the cause of the error but an exception that happens because of how the code handles the first exception.

Comment: What happens if I didn't dispose of it? How can I remove the damage done?

Answer (score 7):

Of course, you need to dispose everything that is disposable, unless you have very good reason to not to dispose.

Put everything into a `using` block by default. If you call `Close` manually this is a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

If a class implements `IDisposable`, then you should dispose it so any resources gets closed/cleaned up asap instead of relying on the garbage collector. Better yet, wrap it in a `using` block so it gets closed even if an exception occurs.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(...))
{
   // do stuff with stream
}
```